# GetTempFileName function for a directory?

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

The .NET Framework defines a `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName` method, which guarantees that the temporary filename it generates will be unique.  As far as I can tell though, although extremely unlikely, this filename *could* be identical to the name of a directory at the same path, meaning that I can't assume that by taking the name of that file, deleting it, and creating a directory of the same name, I'll have a directory with a unique name to any other directory.  Whatsmore, I can't specify the path under which `GetTempFileName` should create its temp file.  There doesn't seem to be an equivalent function to `GetTempFileName` for directories.

Is there a `GetTempFileName` equivalent for creating a unique directory?  If not, what's the best way to create a unique directory at a specified location (ie. I specify the path under which to create the unique directory)?

Comment: Jez the issue is that you use the API which gives you a unique temp file name ( of course inside the system temp folder ) to do some magic and create a directory with such name, this is wrong by definition. You should then edit your question and retitle it in: How can I get unique random not existing directory name?... or similar...

Comment: Be careful with the `GetTempFileName` as it can create a maximum of 65535 temporary files. If your program (or another program) does not remove the files you will have a kind of leak. Once there are 65535 of those files (slowly accumulating) you will see weird problems happening everywhere temporary files are used (using `GetTempFileName`)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` for that task.

Comment: So something like... `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());`?

Comment: Yes this may be the way. Use `Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString())`

Answer (score 11):

Guid works, but if you want a shorter directory name (8.3 format) you can use [`GetRandomFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    public static string GetRandomTempPath()
    {
        var tempDir = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

        string fullPath;
        do
        {
            var randomName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
            fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(tempDir, randomName);
        }
        while (Directory.Exists(fullPath));

        return fullPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
string basePath = @"c:\test\";    // or use Path.GetTempPath

string tempPath;
do
{
    tempPath = Path.Combine(basePath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
} while (Directory.Exists(tempPath));

try
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
}
catch
{
    // something went wrong!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create unique name with Guid.